# How to write the contents of a Scala stream to a file?

Tags: scala, io

I have a Scala stream of bytes that I'd like to write to a file.  The stream has too much data to buffer all of it memory.

As a first attempt, I created an `InputStream` similar to this:

```
class MyInputStream(data: Stream[Byte]) extends InputStream {
  private val iterator = data.iterator
  override def read(): Int = if (iterator.hasNext) iterator.next else -1
}
```

Then I use Apache Commons to write the file:

```
val source = new MyInputStream(dataStream)
val target = new FileOutputStream(file)
try {
  IOUtils.copy(source, target)
} finally {
  target.close
}
```

This works, but I'm not too happy with the performance.  I'm guessing that calling `MyInputStream.read` for every byte introduces a lot of overhead.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might (or might not!) be mistaken that the read side is the source of your performance troubles. It could be the fact that you are using an unbuffered FileOutputStream(...), forcing a separate system call for every byte written.

Here's my take, quick 'n simple:

```
def writeBytes( data : Stream[Byte], file : File ) = {
  val target = new BufferedOutputStream( new FileOutputStream(file) )
  try data.foreach( target.write(_) ) finally target.close
}
```

Comment: Good catch!  I defined a 100 MB test stream: `(1 to 100 * 1024 * 1024).toStream.map(_.toByte)`.  Buffering the output stream improved the average run time from 16.5 seconds to 14.7 seconds.  It doesn't get me the performance I want, but it helps a bit.  I'm guessing it would help more if I had a mechanical hard drive instead of an SSD.

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the winner because it produced the best results in my testing.  It was only slightly better than most of the other techniques, but the difference was enough to be clear.

I learned that `Stream[Byte]` is a really inefficient way to handle data.  The stream itself is the major bottleneck.  `Stream[String]` or `Stream[Array[Byte]]` are much better choices for moving data quickly.

Answer (score 6):

I'd recommend the `java.nio.file` package. With `Files.write` you can write `Array`s of `Byte`s to a `Path` constructed from a filename.

It's up to you how to provide the `Byte`s. You can turn the `Stream` into an `Array` with `.toArray` or you can `take` bytes off the stream one (or a handful) at a time and turn them into arrays.

Here's a simple code block demonstrating the `.toArray` method.

```
import java.nio.file.{Files, Paths}

val filename: String = "output.bin"
val bytes: Stream[Byte] = ...
Files.write(Paths.get(filename), bytes.toArray)
```

Comment: I think the problem @mrog is facing that `.toArray` forces the stream to be materialized into memory and it's too large for that.

Comment: I tried the NIO approach, recursively splitting the stream to get the bytes.  It took 16 seconds to write 100 MB, which is nearly identical in performance to the original `MyInputStream` approach.  The source I'm using is `(1 to 100 * 1024 * 1024).toStream.map(_.toByte)`, which should be plenty fast.  By comparison, copying the same data from one file to another using `Files.copy(Paths.get("/tmp/input"), Paths.get("/tmp/output"), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING)` takes 0.19 seconds.  I feel like I'm missing out on two orders of magnitude of performance.

Comment: I did a performance test on `MyInputStream`, just iterating over the data, but not writing it anywhere.  100 MB took 0.002 seconds.  So, the test stream I'm using clearly isn't the bottleneck.  And using IOUtils.copy to copy the same data from one file to another takes 0.12 seconds (even faster than using NIO), so the file system isn't the bottleneck.

Comment: I goofed when I tested the stream's performance.  Iterating over the stream's contents (without doing anything with the data) actually takes 13.8 seconds, not 0.002 seconds.  So, the stream is the bottleneck.

Answer (score 3):

You should implement the bulk read override in your InputStream implementation:

```
override def read(b: Array[Byte], off: Int, len: Int)
```

`IOUtils.copy` uses that signature to read/write in 4K chunks.

Comment: I tried that and didn't notice any difference in performance.  Maybe that's because I was still relying on the stream iterator to read one byte at a time.  Can you suggest a good implementation of `read(b: Array[Byte], off: Int, len: Int)` that doesn't rely on a stream iterator?

Answer (score 2):

Given that `StreamIterator` reading one byte at a time might be the bottleneck, I've devised a way to write a stream to an`OutputStream` that does not rely on it and is hopefully more efficient:

```
object StreamCopier {
  def copy(data: Stream[Byte], output: OutputStream) = {
    def write(d: Stream[Byte]): Unit = if (d.nonEmpty) {
      val (head, tail) = d.splitAt(4 * 1024)
      val bytes = head.toArray
      output.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length)
      write(tail)
    }
    write(data)
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** Fixed a bug by replacing `data` with `d` inside the tail-recursive `write` function.

This approach uses a recursive approach via `splitAt` to split the stream into the first ~4K and the remainder, write that head it to the `OutputStream` and recurse on the tail of the stream, until `splitAt` returns an empty stream.

Since you have performance benchmarks in place, i'll leave it to you to judge if that turns out to be more efficient.

Comment: I like this approach because it's pretty simple.  I had to refactor it slightly because the outer method was keeping a reference to the stream while the inner method ran, thus consuming tons of memory.

    object StreamCopier2 {
      @tailrec
      def copy(data: Stream[Byte], output: OutputStream): Unit = {
        if (data.nonEmpty) {
          val (head, tail) = data.splitAt(4 * 1024)
          val bytes = head.toArray
          output.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length)
          copy(tail, output)
        }
      }
    }

Comment: Interestingly enough, the new version takes exactly the same amount of time to process 100 MB as my original `MyInputStream` approach.  The major difference is that `MyInputStream` benefits slightly from the addition of a `BufferedOutputStream`, but `StreamCopier2` runs in the same amount of time whether there's a `BufferedOutputStream` or not.  This makes `MyInputStream` with an added `BufferedOutputStream` the winner by a small margin.

Comment: Sorry about that.. That function was completely broken. As you pointed out `data` shouldn't have been used inside of `write` and then i never even kicked off the tail recursion. My fix is a bit different from your suggestion, so see if that makes a difference for you.

Comment: The edited version works, but it's still slow for large streams.  I believe `data` stays in scope until `write` is finished, causing the JVM to garbage collect frequently.  A 1 MB stream takes 0.4 seconds, a 10 MB stream takes 5.1 seconds, which is a little more increase than I'd expect.  I tried a 100 MB stream, but I gave up after many minutes of waiting for it to finish.  Without the nested methods, it's much faster.

Comment: I restarted my IDE and tried again.  A 100 MB stream took 110 seconds, which is almost 7 times longer than the time it takes without nested methods.

Comment: Wow. That's surprising and annoying. The nested function is the canonical pattern for hiding tail-recursive functions. Really curious what's going on there.

Comment: You may have noticed that any time you retrieve values from a `Stream`, those values stay buffered in the `Stream` object forever.  To avoid running out of memory when iterating over large streams, you can't keep any references to the stream head.